# Visual Basic insert into database fails with Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint even though code has try

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following code in a visual basic application:

```
    Try
        Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(myConnString)
            mySelectQuery = "Insert into sponsor_distributions (" & db_fields & ") values (" & db_values & ")"
            myCommand = New SqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection)
            myConnection.Open()
            ra = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            myConnection.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(myConnString)
            mySelectQuery = "Delete from sponsor_distributions WHERE (dist_key = '" & db_key & "')"
            myCommand = New SqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection)
            myConnection.Open()
            ra = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            mySelectQuery = "Insert into sponsor_distributions (" & db_fields & ") values (" & db_values & ")"
            myCommand = New SqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection)
            ra = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            myConnection.Close()
        End Using
    End Try
```

The code fails on

> ra = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

I know the reason for the failure is the fact that the database already contains a record with the same key that I am trying to insert.  But I thought that if the code within the Try failed, the code within the Catch would automatically execute.

Is my assumption regarding Try .... Catch .... End Try incorrect?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say - "I know the reason for the failure is the fact that the database already contains a record with the same key that I am trying to insert"... Are you sure? What error do you get?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  This is the error that I get: SqlException occurred - Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_sponsor_distributions'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.sponsor_distributions'. The duplicate key value is (8551855100001 ).  The statement has been terminated.

Comment: And you are sure you are not trying to insert that row twice? How often is this snippet called? And with which values for db_values? The part you posted if run once, would not cause this error (assuming that dist_key is indeed the only key on the table and db_key matches the key in db_values)

Comment: I AM sure that I am trying to insert the same row twice.  That is why I coded it within a Try ... Catch clause.  I thought that if an error occurred in the Try then the code in the Catch would execute.  If that were the case, the Catch would delete the record with the same key from the database and then insert the new record.  But that is not happening.  The Try stops the process.  Maybe I should move the delete into its own Try ... Catch. This way, if it exists, it will be deleted before the insert executes and if it does not execute, then no harm, no foul.

Comment: Because you're in Debug mode, Visual Studio will jump to the line with error.

Comment: Can't you simply check if the Pkey you're about to insert already exists? `Try/Catch` is not used to control the process' flow (unless you cannot avoid it).

Comment: @Jimi Yes, I can do that.  I guess if I try to read with the primary key and I get a record back, I can delete that record.  Then, when I insert, I would be sure that there is no record with the key that I want to insert.

Comment: The way you're doing it, if the first INSERT fails for *any* reason (not just duplicate record), then it'll run the CATCH code. Which probably isn't what you want. By the looks of it just try and DELETE the record first (it won't error if no records are deleted), then INSERT.

Comment: Or instead of deleting, couldn't you just perform an update if that key exists?

Comment: @Slugsie Thanks.  That is what I ended up doing.